# How to pretty-print a Python list with indices?

Tags: python, list, perl, pretty-print

How can I pretty-print a (possibly nested) Python list **with indices**, similar to the Perl's [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) module, e.g. for `L = ['a', 'b', None, 'c']` the output should be something like this:

```
[
    [0] 'a',
    [1] 'b',
    [2] None,
    [3] 'c',
]
```

Comment: There's a [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#module-pprint) module you can probably experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to get the indices, and use [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#module-pprint) to pretty-print a python list.
For example:

```
pprint.pprint([{num: value} for num, value in enumerate(L)], width=20)
```

and the output is:

```
[{0: 'a'},
 {1: 'b'},
 {2: None},
 {3: 'c'}]
```

Comment: You can flatten the nested lists before using enumerate and pprint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists